# EmEditorでHTML文書作成時にコメントアウト内のURL表示が変

Tags: html, emeditor

パソコンをWindows8.1からWindows10へ新調し、EmEditor Freeもversionを18から最新のVersion 20.1.2にしました。

すると、いままでHTML文書でコメント`<!-- -->`内にURLを書くとコメントと同色でリンクとしては無効になったのが、コメント内でもURL部分だけ青色でリンクとして有効になります。間違ってクリックすると反応して鬱陶しい。

但し、下記みたいにURLをコメント開始記号に直接続けて書くとリンク無効になります。

```
<!--http://hoge.com -->
```

httpの前に空白を入れたり何か２バイト文字を入れると、色が変ってリンク有効となります。

```
<!-- http://hoge.com-->
<!--あhttp://hoge.com-->
```

`表示`＞`現在の設定のプロパティ`／`すべての設定のプロパティ` で旧バージョンでの設定をインポートしましたが、変化無し。
どうすれば元通りに、コメント内のURLも他のコメント文字列同様に表示できますか。

EmEditor ヘルプには、該当する記述が無いみたいです。
http://www.emeditor.org/ja/dlg_properties_link_index.html
EmEditorの更新履歴を見た限り、これに関する変更は見当たりませんでした。
https://jp.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/history/

Answer (score 0):

これは、URL とコメントのどちらを優先して強調するかの問題で、以前のバージョンと現在のバージョンでは、その優先度が異なっているためです。この優先度は、他の EmEditor ユーザーのご意見により少しずつ変更されることがあります。しかし、ユーザーによって意見が異なるため、必ずしてもすべて万人向けというわけではなく、将来的には優先度をカスタマイズできるようにしたいと思います。

間違ってURLをクリックすると反応する問題の回避には、ダブルクリックのみ有効にする方法があると思います。そのためには、設定のプロパティのリンクで、`ダブルクリックのみ有効` をチェックするか、あるいは [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [アクティブな文字列] ページで、[URL] を選択した後、[左クリックしたとき] を `無し` にし、[左ダブルクリックしたとき] を `既定のプログラムでURLを開く` を選択してください。

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。「設定のプロパティのリンクで、ダブルクリックのみ有効 をチェックするか、あるいは [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [アクティブな文字列] ページで、[URL] を選択した後」――との御教示ですが、EmEditor Freeで使用中なためか、そのどちらもダイアログに出てこず、選択可能ではありません（有償のEmEditor Professionalにアップグレードすべき、なのか……？）。こんな風に更新履歴にも見当らない仕様の変動があると、対処しようにも手が打てぬまま受容せざるを得なくなって、困惑します。今後のヴァージョン・アップで「優先度のカスタマイズ」がFree版でも可能となることを祈ります。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。Free版をお使いだったというのは見落としておりました。Free版ではこのような細かい設定ができないようになっていますが、これは設定をできるだけ少なくして初心者にも使いやすくするためでもあります。もし、このような細かい設定を変更されたい場合には、Professional版にアップグレードしてお使いになることをおすすめします。